# Format date in French within a Laravel validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

In my controller, I want to create a validation for a date before the year 2000.

```
'dateofbirth' => 'required|date|after:1960|before:2000-01-01'
```

My validation works; however, I would like to change the format `2000-01-01` with `01-01-2000`.

[image]

In the file `validation.php,` I want to have a message similar to the following.

`The dateofbirth must be a date before 01-01-2002.`

How can I convert this date?

**Edit 02/07/2019**

Here is my Controller. Is it correct ?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
       'dateofbirth' => 'required|date|after:1960|before:2000-01-01'   
    ]);

     Student::create($request->all());
     return redirect()->route('students.index')
           ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
     'dateofbirth.required' => "REQUIRED",
     'dateofbirth.date_format' => "MESSAGE",
     'dateofbirth.after' => "MESSAGE",
     'dateofbirth.before' => "The dateofbirth must be a date before 01-01-2002." 
   ];
}
```

In my file `validation.php` I should put this?

```
'dateofbirth.before' => "The dateofbirth must be a date before 01-01-2002." ,
```

Comment: Are you sending that form to your controller? Can you put your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
'timeStart' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|after:1960|before:2000-01-01'
```

Not sure of the date, but the second part works for sure!

You can do like this:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
      'dateofbirth' => 'required|date|after:1960|before:2000-01-01'
    ]
}

public function messages(){
    return [
      'dateofbirth.required' => "REQUIRED",
      'dateofbirth.date_format' => "MESSAGE",
      'dateofbirth.after' => "MESSAGE",
      'dateofbirth.before' => "The dateofbirth must be a date before 01-01-2002." 
    ]
}
```

The message must be enclosed in double quotation marks if I am not mistaken.

More about validation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation